# store multiple listbox elements into database using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, listbox

1.list box with veriable length
2.submit button
3.i want to store all the elements into database without selecting individual elements when i click on the submit button

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
 function addNewItem()
 {
     var textbox = document.getElementById('MyTextBox');
     var listbox = document.getElementById('MyListBox');
     var newOption = document.createElement('option');
     newOption.value = textbox.value;
     newOption.innerHTML = textbox.value;
     listbox.appendChild(newOption);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="MyTextBox"/>
<input type="button" value="Add Item" onclick="javascript:addNewItem()"/>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="check" name="submit"/><br></br>
<select name="list[]" id="MyListBox" size="10">
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you opened the mysql connection and will close it after this :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['list']){
    foreach ($_POST['list'] as $option){
        mysql_query("insert into [table_name] ([field_name]) values ($option);");
    }
}

?>
```